# Using a projection other than Mercator with proj4js 2.5 and OpenLayers 5.3

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, proj4js, homolosine

I am following the [OpenLayers FAQ](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html#how-do-i-change-the-projection-of-my-map-) regarding the use of coordinate systems that do not rely on the infamous Mercator projection. I thus produced a very small HTML with a simple example that could be later fed to an OpenLayers `View` object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CRS example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>

      var proj4               = proj4;             
      var register            = ol.proj.proj4.register; 
      var getProjection       = ol.proj.get;     

      proj4.defs('EPSG:152160', '+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');
      register(proj4);
      const homolosine = getProjection('EPSG:152160');

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When this file is loaded in the browser the console shows an error message: "Uncaught EPSG:152160". A stack trace is shown:

[image]

This error message is shown both in Chromium and Firefox.

I tried changing the identifier string passed to the `defs` method, but the result is the same. Without the `register` method being applied the OpenLayers `View` object ignores the CRS passed in the `projection` parameter and uses Mercator instead.

How can I use the desired CRS with this software setup?

Comment: igh wasn't supported in early versions of proj4js https://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/UserGuide and although I can't find any more recent relevant documentation there is nothing in the source to suggest it has been added https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/tree/master/lib/projections  You could try using mproj4 as in this example https://github.com/openlayers/f4gna18-frenzy/blob/master/src/reprojection.js

Comment: 152160 is not an EPSG code and EPSG shouldn't be used as the authority. Disclosure: member of EPSG subcommittee.

Comment: @mkennedy I contacted the EPSG in the past about the Homolosine projection but they do not seem to be interested. "EPSG" is the only authority string accepted by Mapserver: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/301733/21532

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `+proj=igh` or `+proj=goode` are currently supported by proj4.js but mproj does support `+proj=goode`  Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/3bjo7rsL/ and the code below.  Error catching is needed to handle "off the world" transforms at the edges.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mproj@0.0.21/dist/mproj.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>

const epsg152160 =
  '+proj=goode +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs';
const epsg3857 =
  '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs';
const transform4326 = mproj(epsg152160);
const transform3857 = mproj(epsg3857, epsg152160);

const homolosine = new ol.proj.Projection({
  units: 'm',
  code: 'EPSG:152160'
});

ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(
  'EPSG:4326',
  homolosine,
  function(coordinate) {
    try {
      return transform4326.forward(coordinate)
    } catch (e) {
      return [undefined, undefined]
    }
  },
  function(coordinate) {
    try {
      return transform4326.inverse(coordinate)
    } catch (e) {
      return [undefined, undefined]
    }
  }
);

ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(
  'EPSG:3857',
  homolosine,
  function(coordinate) {
    try {
      return transform3857.forward(coordinate)
    } catch (e) {
      return [undefined, undefined]
    }
  },
  function(coordinate) {
    try {
      return transform3857.inverse(coordinate)
    } catch (e) {
      return [undefined, undefined]
    }
  }
);

var center = ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', homolosine);

var baseMapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [ baseMapLayer ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: homolosine,
    center: center, 
    zoom: 3
  })
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would not cross my mind that a projection supported by PROJ and GDAL would not be supported by proj4js. Note also that `+proj=goode` is not the Homolosine projection, only `+proj=igh` is.