# MapServ - how to request "default" custom projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, wms, mapserver

I have a GeoTIFF (USGS Land Use / Land Cover) which works great with AERSURFACE.  If I use gdalinfo to get the coordinate system, it comes back as:

> PROJCRS["unknown",
> BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
> DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
> ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
> LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
> PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
> ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
> ID["EPSG",4269]],
> CONVERSION["Albers Equal Area",
> METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
> ID["EPSG",9822]],
> PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",23,
> ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
> ID["EPSG",8821]],
> PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-96,
> ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
> ID["EPSG",8822]],
> PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",29.5,
> ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
> ID["EPSG",8823]],
> PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45.5,
> ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
> ID["EPSG",8824]],
> PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
> LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
> ID["EPSG",8826]],
> PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
> LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
> ID["EPSG",8827]]],
> CS[Cartesian,2],
> AXIS["easting",east,
> ORDER[1],
> LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
> ID["EPSG",9001]]],
> AXIS["northing",north,
> ORDER[2],
> LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
> ID["EPSG",9001]]]]

9822 isn't a valid EPSG code (??any more??) but I've seen a custom definition similar to this:

> PROJECTION
> "proj=aea"
> "lat_1=29.83333333333334"
> "lat_2=45.83333333333334"
> "lat_0=37.5"
> "lon_0=-96"
> "x_0=0"
> "y_0=0"
> "ellps=WGS84"
> "datum=WGS84"
> "units=m"
> "no_defs"
> END

I'm trying to set up a MapServer (for Windows) using the custom definition so that I can serve up sections of the large (16GB) image.  When I try to make a GetMap request, how do I specify the "default" projection for my map?  The SRS/CRS parameter is required and must be specified with an EPSG name.  But, in my case, I'm just trying to get whatever is defined for the map.

Comment: One way is to add a custom projection with a fake EPSG code. A well known example from the past is EPSG:900913. In earlier days it was enough to add a new line into a text file named `epsg` that ships with MapServer but with the new versions of MapServer and Proj library it may not be as easy any more. But MapServer can re-project on-the-fly so it should be fine to use your image as it is and use any SRS/CRS in GetMap (you must configure what codes you support in the mapfile). WMS does not have a concept of default SRS/CRS but user must always define the desired output in GetMap request.

Comment: Could you add the LAYER part of your mapfile and a link to some test data if possible?

Comment: In that place code 9822 means the Albers Equal Area method  `METHOD["Albers Equal Area", ID["EPSG",9822]]` just like 9001 in another place means metre `["metre",1, ID["EPSG",9001]`. This definition does not contain EPSG code for the complete projected coordinate system.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301733/mapserver-using-a-crs-for-which-there-is-no-epsg-code for similar issue

Comment: epsg:9822 is a valid EPSG CRS code, it isn't however anything to do with North American datum or Albers Equal Area ~ https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/9822